# It's possible to create an accordion ListView with Nativescript?

Tags: listview, accordion, nativescript

I'm developing an app with Nativescript, but I have a problem, I don't know How can I implement an accordion with ListView?.

In the page news says about a plugin, but I have errors with him.

The plugin is --> **nativescript-accordion**

The console says, **"addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView android.widget.AdapterView"**

I'm really appreciated your time
Thanks

Comment: Best would be if you post errors or what you done till now

Comment: It's now updated.

Comment: Will need the UI and logic you're using to know what's happening